# USSD call without user confirmation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code for calling from the app:

`let number : String = "*10*60#"
 if  let url : URL = URL(string: "tel://\(number)"){
   UIApplication.shared.open(url)}`

But it asks for the permission of the user
and that's ok but I don't want to let the user know the USSD code that I want to call.
I'm using this for calling to USSD codes for buying packages of mobile internet. Is there a way of changing that? I mean change the text so that instead of the number that this is going to call, it would say, "do you want to purchase this package?"

[image]

Comment: there is no way to hide phone number, and I hope will newer be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user cannot see what number you are calling before granting permission, what stops you from calling a premium-rate number (like a 900 or 976 number in the USA) that charges $1000 to the user's cellular phone bill for the call?

Answer: nothing. That's why Apple does not let you call a number without user approval.

Also, even if you show the number, this sounds suspiciously like something Apple would reject on the grounds of not using Apple's own In-App Purchase system.